# Transpose + Sum Strings in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a dynamic column of strings and want to perform both a transpose and sum.  An example of the column and the ultimate goal is below:

```
**VARIABLE COLUMN TITLE**
VPPTest1
VPPTest2
VPPTest3
VPPTest4
VPPTest5
VPPTest6
```

I am trying to get a formula (or series of formula) to create the following.  Could also be done with VBA if that's easiest.

```
VPPTotal = VPPTest1 + VPPTest2 + VPPTest3 + VPPTest4 + VPPTest5 + VPPTest6
```

where everything is a string and output the summation formula into a cell.

*NOTE* The output is a STRING not an integer of number value.  The actual output will be concatenation of strings that make the VPPTotal above.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide a before/after picture with some sample data?

Comment: I have provided the same data and the exact output as a string that I am looking for in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a basic loop in `vba`,

This snippet sums all the values between "A2" and the last non-empty cell in column "A", and appends the sum to the end of column "A"

```
Dim row As Integer
Dim col as String
Dim total as Integer
col = "A"
row = 2
While Range(col & row) <> ""
  total = total + Range(col & row)
  row = row + 1
Wend
Range(col & row) = total
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: I modified to have input/output as a string but works great, thanks!